# It is possible that calling asp.net function as being used javascript codes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Forinstance there is a asp.net function. I want to run that function from javascript codes. is this possible ? if it is , how?

Comment: You are looking for Ajax.  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way to do it, its a quick fix, cunning, but it works!

just add a asp button somewhere in the page and in the button click function, call the method you want to call from javascript.

suppose you have a c# function in your code behind like

```
public void doSomething() {...}
```

then the button function will something be like:

```
protected void button1_onClick(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

and your aspx page will have a button like this, make sure you add style property to hide the button (if you want to hide it)

```
<asp:button ID="button1" runat="server" text="" style="display:none"
 class="NinjaButton" onClick="button1_onClick" />
```

now, when you want to call the function, just click the invisible button through javascript (or even better, jquery)

suppose you want to call the function when the mouse moves over a div, you can do this:

```
<div id="divSomething" OnMouseOver="$('.NinjaButton').click()">
....
</div>
```

Remember, the NinjaButton in the jquery on mouseover is just the class name of that button. make sure you dont have that class to any other button!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as *asp.net function*. If you mean a .NET method which is defined in the code behind of an ASP.NET page you could take a look at [PageMethods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx). And here's an example using [jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/26/436639.aspx). Scott Gu has also [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/26/436639.aspx) about them. Note that the method needs to be static.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I have nothing against downvotes, only they need to be justified by a comment explaining why the answer was wrong.